# Creating animated Super Saiyan Effect in CSS - Where to Start?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a decent knowledge in CSS and some JQuery, but I had an idea for something a bit ambitious (at least for myself).

I'm looking to create the animated Super Saiyan glow/aura effect in pure CSS.

[image: aura effect]

I'm not quite sure where to begin or what I should learn in order to complete this project, so I was hoping for some direction if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would use CSS clipping masks with HTML5.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/#toc-animation-of-clip-path (direct link)

---

**The idea**

There's an awesome example which moves when hovered, you can make that effect easily.

```
img:hover {
  clip-path: polygon(0px 208px, 146.5px 207px, 147px 141.2px, ...);
  animate: star 3s;
}

@keyframes star {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(0px 208px, 146.5px 207px, 147px 141.2px, ...);
  },
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(0px 208px, 146.5px 207px, 147px 141.2px, ...);
  }
}
```

---

**Making the shape using the online generator**

If you want to make the basic shape of the 'effect' fast. You can use [THIS WEBSITE](http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator)

---

**You an use this basic CSS animation and make it even prettier:**
http://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/17dd591f451f4757366faf3c9246504b

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900);
body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.note {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.element {   
  background-color: #f1c40f; 
  color: white;
  width: 500px; 
  height: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: justify;
  shape-inside: polygon(250px 0, 350px 170px, 500px 180px, 380px 320px, 450px 500px, 250px 420px, 50px 500px, 120px 320px, 0px 180px, 150px 170px );
  shape-padding: 10px;
  transition: all 3s ease; 
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(250px 0, 350px 170px, 500px 180px, 380px 320px, 450px 500px, 250px 420px, 50px 500px, 120px 320px, 0px 180px, 150px 170px );
} 
.element:hover{ 
   shape-inside: polygon(250px 0, 500px 0, 500px 180px, 500px 320px, 500px 500px, 250px 500px, 0 500px, 0 320px, 0 180px, 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(250px 0, 500px 0, 500px 180px, 500px 320px, 500px 500px, 250px 500px, 0 500px, 0 320px, 0 180px, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<p class="note">Hover over the element to see its shape animate. <span style="color:red">Please see browser support note at beginning of article.</span></p>
<div class="element">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel ratione qui voluptatum quod et quaerat dolorum odio consequuntur dolores! Ipsum commodi mollitia maiores expedita reiciendis ducimus qui unde! Odio molestias!
  </p>
</div>
```

I'll edit my answer with more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with shadow effects and animations in CSS3. Look here for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Some cool example of this techinque: http://zurb.com/playground/css-boxshadow-experiments

EDIT: As Kees Sonnema suggested using clip-path is a great idea, helping you to control shape. Shadow effects(http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_shadows.asp) will make your "flame" to glow and then you can animate it by standard CSS 3 animations.